# App engine developer console not able to access text search

Tags: google-app-engine

In app engine developer console not able to access text search for one of my projects but able to get data through application. Is there any setting I am missing?

I got below message when i tried to access search inside developer console.

> Add full-text search functionality to your app with the App Engine Search service. This service stores structured documents in indexes, and lets you perform faceted queries on document fields. You can browse and search your indexes from this panel.

Comment: You need to be clearer... the way I understand your issue now... you have data in the datastore, and you're trying to search with the Search API product. Two completely different things....

Comment: I mean i am able to access text search data through application.I am not talking about datastore.